# My Ajax function is making double request

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is my function to check if the coupon code is valid or not.

```
function checkCoupon(str){

   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
               alert('success');
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","https://www.example.com/inc/checkCoupon?id=45&coupon="+str,true);

        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

I am using `<input onchange="checkCoupon(this.value)" placeholder="Coupon">` to call this.

The problem is, It is making two different calls. First `https://` version of the page then it was immediately canceled after that it makes another call on `http://` version which is rejected because of **mixed-content**.

I have also checked it I have more than one function to do the same work but I have an only single function on this page.

Here is the snap of network tab in Inspect Element >> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnaab.jpg

Above is `https://` and below is `http://`.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does something call checkCoupon(str) more than once?

Comment: No, I had already checked for it but there is no other element making the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have some active http content when you're making the https request. For more information, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content#Mixed_active_content).

A question though, why don't you just force the entire site's communication to be via https in the first place? This can be done in the htaccess file.
Example:

```
#Rewrite everything to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I have done it already to redirect all `http://` to `https://` URL via `.htaccess` but everything is in vain. I have also tried your code especially but it is still not working. @Martin

Comment: Odd, I never had the problem myself personally, but judging from your error code, it does look like active http content error, which should be fixed by forcing all communication to be https by default.

Comment: Yes, I know. It never happens to me too. I never had any URL issues like that. I will have to redevelop everything if It does not allow it.

Comment: Thanks @Martin. you assumption helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There was indeed something wrong in the `.htaccess` file. This type of problem actually happens because of `.htaccess`. I will answer half of the question because I don't know the answer to the other half.

This was my `.htaccess` code for redirection to **www** then **https://**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This is actually alright. What I have missed is another code below it. This below code is used to force the trailing slashes in URL.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

As you can see, what I have missed is the last row in this code. I have forced trailing slashes to `http://www.exaple.com` which is actually supposed to be `https://www.exaple.com`. I have missed `http://` here which is actually supposedly be `https://`.

Another half answer, which I don't know is: It is still making the double request for every AJAX query call. I have a guess about it, It must be due to the `non-www` to `www` redirection then `http://` to `https://` redirection. It is still my guess though.

Thanks to @Martin, I at least got the idea about my fault.